# Single bit extraction from register while debugging

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded

Currently I am debugging an embedded application in Eclipse IDE. I've got some registers to inspect, mosly ony one bit from it. Is there any way to tell Eclipse to watch only one bit in chosen register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solutions are usually the best. You can always create another variable just for debugging purposes

```
myDebugVar = (mainVar & MASK_THAT_EXTRACTS_YOUR_BIT) >> SOME_SHIFT;
```

Now watch your new 'myDebugVar' and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

It is inefficient, unnecessary and error prone to modify the code in order to create an artificial watch variable.  The appropriate solution is to display the register value in hexadecimal.

In hex, each group of four bits corresponds to a single hex digit, so it is easy to locate the bit of interest, and with only 15 hex digits/bit patterns, it is a simple operation with experience to mentally extract the single bit.